# VB.NET connect to Win2008 SQL server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, connection, dataadapter

I am running Visual Studio 2008 on my Windows XP Professional SP3 box.

The server is on Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1

The server is on our network, and I am able to ping it via the DNS name used in my connection string, as well as by IP address.

During the ObjDa.Fill(dsReturn) statement, this error occurs.

> No error message available, result code:
>   DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).

```
    Dim strQuery As String = "select * from sys.Tables" 
    Dim strConn As String = "Server=dev.xxxxxxx.vmc;" & _
              "Uid=xxxx;PWD=xxxxx;Database=report1;Integrated Security=False;"

    Dim ObjDa As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, strConn)

    Try
        Dim dsReturn As DataSet = New DataSet
        ObjDa.Fill(dsReturn)
        ObjDa.Dispose()
        Return dsReturn
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim strError as string = ex.Message()
    End Try
```

---

**EDIT**

---

I have changed my code to use the following line, per Tim's comment suggestion

```
Dim ObjDa As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(pStrQuery, strConnection)
```

Now, I am getting This message

> Login failed for user 'vmc\adam'.

When I connect through Remote Desktop Connection to that server, log in with my windows credentials, and bring up the SQL Management Studio... the Authentication type is 'Windows Authentication' for 'VMC\adam', and I don't type in a password.

But, when I use those same credentials in my connection string, it errors out.  Ideas?

---

**EDIT**

---

I found a site that suggested using the following settings in the connection string, and removing the username and password, to enable windows authentication.

**This is now working.**

```
integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: Why are you using `OleDbDataAdapter` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`? You should also use a `SqlConnection`. Use also `Using-Statement` for connection and dataadapter to ensure that they are disposed(and closed) even in case of an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a uid/password combo and set integrated security to false, it attempts to look for a sql server login as opposed to a windows login. You will want to change your connection string to this if you want to use Windows Authentication.

```
Server=dev.xxxxxxx.vmc;Database=report1;Integrated Security=True;
```